# Pine Script: print not NaN values of a series

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The following script creates a label for each element of the series. How can one create a label only on candles with corresponding `not NaN` values?

```
//@version=5
indicator('Print text values', overlay=true)
length = input(2)
up1 = ta.pivothigh(high, length, length)

l = label.new(bar_index-length, high, str.tostring(up1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a `na()` function to test if the value is `na`.

So, you can do the following.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Print text values', overlay=true)
length = input(2)
up1 = ta.pivothigh(high, length, length)

if not na(up1)
    l = label.new(bar_index-length, high, str.tostring(up1))
```

Comment: Is there another way to print series values rather than `label.new`?

Comment: No, because `up1`'s value is not constant.